# Game build in unity3d project transfer from a previous developer

Tags: unity, c#, project-management

Can someone help or give me some idea what are the necessary deliverables from a previous developer that I need to ask regarding the game project transfer?

The situation is, there is a company that is developing our game in unity3d and it is already available in Apple store and Playstore. They developed it from scratch and on our part, we are just doing the game testing process. So now, we are going to ask them to transfer the entire project development to us. The company is in another country so we are just communicating thru emails, and we never done the communication by video calls.

And That's it. what are the things they need to transfer to us?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your game exists in a single Unity project, the bare minimum that you'll *need* from them is the project folder that the project belongs to. This is enough to build and run the project and you'll have access to all of the code and assets used in the project.

Anything beyond that is somewhat optional, but it may be a good idea to ask for their acquisition, assuming they were used by the previous developers.

- **Asset Project Files**: Things such as Photoshop PSDs, Maya Projects, etc. Anything that may increase productivity and make it easier to make changes to existing game assets.
- **Game Design Documents**: This is assuming that the previous developers had creative responsibilities on the game, but if so, it may be a good idea to ask for any documents they've used so that you have an appropriate understanding of what they were going on.
- **Project Management**: Anything from a to-do-list text file to a Trello or Slack. Anything that was used by the previous developers, and may alert you of existing bugs or unfinished systems in the project, so that you know how to properly continue where they left off.
- **Unity Version**: If they're not using the latest version of Unity, it would probably be a good idea to know what version they were using, since large projects may contain many breaking changes when ported to a newer version.
- **Unity Asset Store Extensions**: Most assets that any previous development team used will be included in the Project file, and will work fine, but I can imagine some that used advanced DRM/Authentication systems may pose a problem when launched on a new system. It may be a good idea to ask for a list of third-party assets that the previous developers used, not only so you know what to expect if you encounter problems, but also so you'll have the same tools that they used for development.

You should be able to communicate with the previous developers if you encounter any problems with the transition, or find out that there's something you need that they haven't provided.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, the list you've mention is really helpful.   Most especially the "Unity Version", I didn't considered about that. At some point from that project folder, I can re-build it to check if they send us the complete and running version, right?

Comment: @I.Am.Alo Yes. You can try to build and run the project they send you from the editor, and if it doesn't work because of any missing files, you can send them the error you get and they should be able to figure out what they need to send you.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for guiding @Nick Wilson